# MySQL - Find a list of department name that one or more of employers whose name is listed as top 5 common name

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I want to find a list of DepName that has one or more of employers who their name is listed as top 5 common name in this table.

```
TABLE Department (
DepName varchar(10),
Emp_id varchar(10),
);
TABLE Employer(
Emp_id varchar(10),
Emp_name varchar(10),
nameId varchar(10),
);
TABLE Name (
nameID varchar(10),
name varchar(10)
);
```

I could figure out to get top 5 common names

```
SELECT n.name, COUNT(n.name) as commonName
FROM Name n
GROUP BY n.name
ORDER BY commonName DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

This will print out top 5 common names, for example,

```
Alex 15
Kimberly 10
Alexa 39
Robert 21
John 50
```

But I couldn't make this query work as a subquery in a query to find the list of Department name like

```
SELECT d.DepName FROM Department d
JOIN Employer e ON d.Emp_id = e.Emp_id 
AND JOIN Name n ON e.nameID = n.nameID
WHERE n.name = (SELECT COUNT(n.name) as commonName
        FROM Name n
        GROUP BY n.name
        ORDER BY commonName DESC 
        LIMIT 5)
```

I want to make this query to print out like this,

```
DepName
Marketing 
Finance 
Human Resource
```

as those departments has one or more of the employers.
How can I fix the query to get the right result?

Comment: `WHERE n.name = (SELECT COUNT(n.name) as commonName`   I do not think n.name will ever be found when you are selecting `COUNT(n.name)`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line

```
n.name = (SELECT COUNT(n.name) as commonName.....
```

`n.name` should have the list of names.

```
with res as (
SELECT n.name, COUNT(n.name) as commonName
FROM Name n
GROUP BY n.name
ORDER BY commonName DESC 
LIMIT 5)

SELECT d.DepName FROM Department d
JOIN Employer e ON d.Emp_id = e.Emp_id 
AND JOIN Name n ON e.nameID = n.nameID
WHERE n.name = select name from res;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT d.DepName FROM Department d
JOIN Employer e ON d.Emp_id = e.Emp_id 
AND JOIN Name n ON e.nameID = n.nameID
WHERE n.name = (SELECT DISTINCT(n.name)
        FROM Name n
        GROUP BY n.name
        ORDER BY COUNT(n.name) DESC 
        LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: idk why it says that the first code is not valid at this point for this server version and the second one "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: I will say use one more ```where n.name = select name from ( select  n.name, ........) ``` and one more thing don't use the same varaible name 'n' for join table and subquery. Use diff variable